# Use library Windows.Networking.Sockets ( metro app ) in a dekstop app c#

Tags: c#, sockets, microsoft-metro

Recently i've developped a c# metro app which works well and now I want to developp the same app in c#. So I've done few things to enable the use of the metro app library thanks to this [website](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/457335/How-to-call-WinRT-APIs-from-NET-desktop-apps) the library windows.networking.proximity still working, windows.security.cryptography also but apparently windows.networking.sockets doesn't work.
The goal in this part of my code, is just to receive data sent from a smartphone by wifi:

```
namespace OpenItForMeDesktop{
class Server
{
    private StreamSocketListener serverListener;
    public static String port = "3011";
    public static String adressIP = "192.168.173.1";
    private HostName hostName;

    //Initialize the server
    public Server()
    {
        serverListener = new StreamSocketListener();
        hostName = new HostName(adressIP);
        listen();
    }

    //Create the listener which is waiting for connection
    private async void listen()
    {
        serverListener.ConnectionReceived += OnConnection;
        try
        {

            //await serverListener.BindEndpointAsync(hostName, port);
            await serverListener.BindServiceNameAsync(port);
            MainWindow.Current.UpdateLog("Listening for Connection(s)");
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            MainWindow.Current.UpdateLog("Exception throw in Listen : " + exception);
        }

    }

    //When a connection appears, this function his called
    private async void OnConnection(StreamSocketListener sender, StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
    {

        MainWindow.Current.UpdateLog("A message has been received...");
        if (MainWindow.Current.loadingPage)
        {
            MainWindow.Current.UpdateLog("wait please");
        }
        else
        {

            DataReader reader = new DataReader(args.Socket.InputStream);
            try
            {
                while (true)
                {

                    reader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;
                    // Read first 4 bytes (length of the subsequent string).
                    uint sizeFieldCount = await reader.LoadAsync(sizeof(uint));
                    if (sizeFieldCount != sizeof(uint))
                    {
                        return;
                    }

                    // Read the string.
                    uint stringLength = reader.ReadUInt32();
                    uint actualStringLength = await reader.LoadAsync(stringLength);
                    if (stringLength != actualStringLength)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    String message = reader.ReadString(actualStringLength);
                    MainWindow.Current.receiveMessage(message);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                // If this is an unknown status it means that the error is fatal and retry will likely fail.
                if (SocketError.GetStatus(exception.HResult) == SocketErrorStatus.Unknown)
                {
                    throw;
                }

                MainWindow.Current.UpdateLog("Read stream failed with error: " + exception.Message);
            }
        }
    }




}
```

}

`
When I build this code there is no error which is thrown, and when I use wireshark to see the packet sent from my smarpthone, I received only packet with the flag [SYN] and not the 3 first packets I received when i'm using my metro app [SYN]/[SYN,ACK]/[ACK] for the handshake.
Is someone as any idea why this is happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, it was quite stupid, it the firewall of windows which was blocking my app.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add

```
<Capability Name="privateNetworkClientServer" />
```

to the Package.appxmanifest?